# Building a wiki like data model in rails question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I have a data model in which I would like to have an item that has a description that can be edited. I would like to also keep track of all edits to the item. I am running into issues with my current strategy, which is:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :current_edit,
           :class_name => "Edit",
           :foreign_key => "current_edit_id"
  has_many :edits
end

class Edit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Can the Item have multiple associations to the same class like this?

I was thinking that I should switch to keeping track of the edit version in the Edit object and then just sorting the `has_many` relationship base on this version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can. But you have to use `belongs_to` not `has_one`. Then your models have to look like:

```
(Item, current_edit_id, ...)
(Edit, item_id, ....)
```

The rails doc explains this in more detail: [Is it a belongs_to or has_one association?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)